# How to make the brand button in bootstrap header visually select first tab?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have this bootstrap code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!--
        <input id="test"/>
        <input id="test2"/>
        -->

        <div id="myTabs" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="brand" href="#tab-01" aria-controls="tab-01" data-toggle="tab">Pal</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab-01" aria-controls="tab-01" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 01</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-02" aria-controls="tab-02" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 02</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-03" aria-controls="tab-03" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 03</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div id="myTabPanes" class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-01">qqq</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-02">ggg</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-03">jjj</div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-beta1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mvc.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But for the `<a class="brand" href="#tab-01" aria-controls="tab-01" data-toggle="tab">Pal</a>` big brand button on the header. I want it so that if it gets clicked, the first tab is selected. I managed to put in those aria-controls and data-toggle and href attributes so that if it gets clicked then, the tab switches. However there is no visual effect. As in if another tab was selected, and I click the brand button, the tab indent doesn't change, even though the tab switches. How do I get it to highlight the first tab?

I would like a way to do this without any javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain CSS, then add this to your style code.

```
.brand:visited + .nav-collapse > .nav.nav-tabs > li:first-of-type > a {
  background-color: #e7e7e7; //or the color that corresponds to your "active" class
}
```

Explanation :

This means when `.brand` is visited, the the element that is placed immediately after it which is `.nav-collapse` and the element inside it which is `.nav.nav-tabs` and the first of the `<li>` element inside it and finally adds the `background-color` to the anchor inside it.(making it look like its active when `brand` is clicked).

You can also add a class to the `<a>` Tab01 and replace `li:first-of-type > a` with `.<that_class_name>`

Comment: But with this, I have to define my own style for how visually the bootstrap class `active` is. How can I just set it to the bootstrap active class instead of defining my own? Does bootstrap not have this feature in it's own JS?

Comment: CSS really doesn't have the ability to modify an object in the same manner as JavaScript, so in short - no. You cannot add a class dynamically using pure CSS. You asked for without any JS, so this is the best solution without it.

Comment: Does bootstrap have like an attribute you can attach to the branding tag which you can put in the tab name, so that if it gets clicked, it can indent that tab? That would be useful.

Comment: Nope sorry buddy :) Although you can also try another trick. Place another `<li>` tag along with others with class="active" and default `display:none` attribute. Now when `.brand:visited`, make that `<li>`'s display:block and the second one as `display:none`. Let me know if you understood me.

Comment: Basically create 2 `<li>` tags, one with `class="active"` and hide-show each of them when brand is clicked.